# Automatic creation of constructor, based on parent class' constructor (C++)

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

Here is a code I would like to get to work:

```
template <class A>
class B : public A {
public:
  // for a given constructor in A, create constructor with identical parameters,
  // call constructor of parent class and do some more stuff
  B(...) : A(...) {
    // do some more stuff
  }
};
```

Is it possible to achieve behavior described by above example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No this is currently not possible in C++. It's called "perfect forwarding", and is allowed in C++0x. You can simulate it by producing overloads of your constructor up to a fixed maximum (like, say, 8 parameters), both for const and non-const references. This is still not perfect (temporaries won't be forwarded as temporaries), but usually works in practice:

```
template<typename T1>
B(T1 &a1):A(a1) { 
  // do some more stuff
}

template<typename T1>
B(T1 const &a1):A(a1) { 
  // do some more stuff
}

template<typename T1, typename T2>
B(T1 &a1, T2 &a2):A(a1, a2) { 
  // do some more stuff
}

template<typename T1, typename T2>
B(T1 const &a1, T2 const &a2):A(a1, a2) { 
  // do some more stuff
}

template<typename T1, typename T2>
B(T1 const &a1, T2 &a2):A(a1, a2) { 
  // do some more stuff
}

template<typename T1, typename T2>
B(T1 &a1, T2 const &a2):A(a1, a2) { 
  // do some more stuff
}

// ...
```

The generation can be automated using Boost.Preprocessor or some script, but it's not exactly nice, since the amount of overloads grows fast.

So in short - no write your constructors yourself until C++0x is available, which supports *both* perfect forwarding for any function, and special constructor forwarding (`"using A::A;"`).

Comment: Please read my answer.
Is this what you meant by "using A::A" ?
Or is it something different?

Answer (score 2):

I've dig through STL and based on what I found there, I settled on this code:

```
template <class Data>
class Node : public Data {
public:

  template<typename... _Args>
  Node (_Args&&... __args) : Data (std::forward<_Args>(__args)...) {
  }

  // ...
};
```

It works with a command:

> g++ -std=c++0x -c code.cpp

Comment: It would help to mention what version of g++ you used.

Comment: g++-4.4 Avaliable in current Ubuntu in gcc-snapshot package.

Comment: [Those identifiers aren't meant to be used by you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier). You probably should have mentioned C++0x was an option for you in the question, by the way. This is the closest thing to constructor inheritance, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the lately released article

[Use C++0x's Inheriting Constructors to Reduce Boilerplate Code in Class Hierarchies](http://www.devx.com/cplus/10MinuteSolution/42828)

on http://www.devx.com.

It probably describes a *future* solution for your problem.